# Show total graph in a particular time: Highcharts, Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So What I am trying to accomplish is little tricky. Actually I am creating a Line Chart using Highcharts.

The Chart is working fine and its been made scrollable. so that the data may look like flowing like live stream.

But the problem is that I want the whole chart to be displayed properly in a particular time.(the whole chart to be displayed within 13 sec. time frame. ). But my chart is not doing that . it takes some time extra to display the Whole Chart.

I can't say that my Approach is correct as per my requirements. so I am gonna put my code here so that you can check

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('abc.csv', function(data) {
var lines = [] ;
lines = data.split('\n');
console.log(lines);


var ecgData=[];
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
if(lineNo >= 0)
    {

    ecgData[lineNo-0] = parseFloat(lineContent.substring(lineContent.lastIndexOf(",")+1) );
      //gibber=500;

    //m=m+500;
    }//console.log('PPG Data', ppgData[ppgNo-0])

});

//console.log(ecg);
console.log(ecgData);



const drawAnimationDuration = 13000 ;
Highcharts.chart('ecg', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
         zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',
        scrollablePlotArea: {
      minWidth: 2000,
      scrollPositionX: 0
    }
    },
    credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
    title: {
        text: 'ECG Data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
         lineWidth: 0,
  minorGridLineWidth: 0,
  lineColor: 'transparent',
        crosshair: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'ECG Peaks'
        }
    },
   tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '',
      //  lineWidth: 1,
        data: ecgData,
          animation: {
           duration: drawAnimationDuration
         }

    } ]
});
setTimeout(() => {
    $('.highcharts-scrolling').animate({
    scrollLeft: $('.highcharts-container').width()
  }, drawAnimationDuration, 'linear');
}, drawAnimationDuration)
});

</script>
```

Here is the Working **Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/bek85hf1/3/

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Abnit Chauhan, What is the exact result you want to achieve? I have wrapped `getClipBox` method to animate all series (not just the visible part), but I'm not sure if you want to achieve that result? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/56Luxbt3/

Comment: All series is animated but its not flowing. In the fiddle . all the data is not visible as it is not sliding. @ppotaczek

Comment: Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gbfv5uz3/ Is that the result you want to achieve?

Comment: your Fiddle is quite nice according to keep time in mind, @ppotaczek just two thing. You are adding an extra poit 0 at the starting point. and the chart starts sliding without reaching the end of the frame

Comment: I don't add any points to the chart. I have changed `easing` property and calculated delay. Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4x9pvtds/

Comment: perfect @ppotaczek. If You could elaborate this in Answer Section so that I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `getClipBox` method to animate animate all series (not just the visible part), calculate delay based on the chart dimensions and change animation `easing`:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'getClipBox', function(proceed, animation, finalBox) {
        var result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        if (finalBox) {
            return {
                x: 0,
                width: this.chart.plotWidth
            }
        }

        return result;
    });
}(Highcharts));


var xValues = [];
xValues = [...];


const drawAnimationDuration = 13000;
var chart = Highcharts.chart('ecg', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        ...,
        animation: {
            duration: drawAnimationDuration,
            easing: function(t) {
                return t;
            }
        }
    }]
});

var delay = drawAnimationDuration / chart.plotWidth * chart.plotSizeX;

setTimeout(() => {
    $('.highcharts-scrolling').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('.highcharts-container').width()
    }, drawAnimationDuration, 'linear');
}, delay)
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4x9pvtds/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts